# A btnclick Function calls another function,but the call not in the btnclick function

Tags: c#, asp.net

consider the following:
code for buttonclick fn in .cs file :

```
protected void additembtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
          DataTable dt = createTemptable();
            dt = (DataTable)Session["dfdtemptable"];
            this.DFDLOVlst.DataSource = dt;
            this.DFDLOVlst.DataBind();
            this.txtLOVCode.Visible = true;
            this.txtLOVvalue.Visible = true;
            MDIngrdientsCode.Show();
}
```

this is the on_row clicked fn of the datagrid

```
protected void OnFindSelect(int Value)
        { 
                }
```

code for findbtn click:

```
protected void btnFind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.FindLookup.SetLookup();
            this.FindLookup.SearchLookup();
            this.MdFindLookup.Show();
      }
```

When the find button is clicked,the lookup control gets loaded with values from database.On selecting any row the selected row values will be added to corresponding text boxs and data grid.
The additembtnclick is to add new entry to the datagrid.The user can add new values or can click the find and select a row and update its values in the datagrid.
Theres no problem when the user adds fresh values .When the user click the find and select a particular row.The values gets add to correspondind fieldls..And now if the user clicks the additem button to add new values to already existing values in datagrid then the fn onfindselected(fn for the onrowclicked event for the lookup control containg datagrid) is called automatically,but the call is not in the button click fn..

Can't figure out whats wrong..?

Comment: Edit your tag. This should be asp.net not "asp-classic"

Comment: button click inside gridview wont work,try OnRowCommand of gridview.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that theOnFindSelect is not an event handler itself. It is probably being called from another event handler (or more than 1). Try looking for all calls to it and see if that makes sense